# How to display the line color in the legend with kdeplot

Tags: python, seaborn, displot, kdeplot

I am wanting to overlay different 2D density plots over each other using the `kdeplot()` function from `seaborn`, however the color of the contours aren't appearing in the legend. How would I be able to update the legend with the color?

Code example:

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.kdeplot(x = np.random.random(30), y = np.random.random(30), label = "dist1", ax=ax)
sns.kdeplot(x = np.random.random(30) + 1, y = np.random.random(30) + 1, label = "dist2", ax=ax)
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: Output plot]

I'm using seaborn v0.12.0

Answer (score 2):

Found a way to work around the issue. By extracting the colour in the colourcycle, you can manually set the colour of `kdeplot()` as well as construct the handles for the legend.

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.lines as mlines

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
handles = []
# Extracting next colour in cycle
color = next(ax._get_lines.prop_cycler)["color"]
sns.kdeplot(x = np.random.random(30), y = np.random.random(30), color = color, label = "dist1", ax=ax)
handles.append(mlines.Line2D([], [], color=color, label="dist1"))

color = next(ax._get_lines.prop_cycler)["color"]
sns.kdeplot(x = np.random.random(30) + 1, y = np.random.random(30) + 1, color = color, label = "dist2", ax=ax)
handles.append(mlines.Line2D([], [], color=color, label="dist1"))


ax.legend(handles = handles)
```

[Output plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4G74E.png)

Answer (score 2):

- It's easier create a [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) with a label column, and let the plot API manage the legend handles and labels. In addition to making plotting easier, it's easier to perform additional analysis on the data in a dataframe.
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.4.3`, `matplotlib 3.5.2`, `seaborn 0.12.0`**

### Create a DataFrame

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(2022)  # for the same sample data each time

# list of dataframes; create each dataframe and use assign to add a label column
df_list = [pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.random(30),
                         'y': np.random.random(30)}).assign(label='d1'),
           pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.random(30) + 1,
                         'y': np.random.random(30) + 1}).assign(label='d2')]

# combine the list of dataframes with concat
df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)

# display(df.head())
          x         y label
0  0.009359  0.564672    d1
1  0.499058  0.349429    d1
2  0.113384  0.975909    d1
3  0.049974  0.037820    d1
4  0.685408  0.794270    d1

# display(df.tail())
           x         y label
55  1.829995  1.251087    d2
56  1.626445  1.241247    d2
57  1.871438  1.841468    d2
58  1.625907  1.020932    d2
59  1.130638  1.894918    d2
```

### [`sns.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html)

```py
# plot the dataframe in a figure level plot
g = sns.displot(kind='kde', data=df, x='x', y='y', hue='label')
```

[image]

### [`sns.kdeplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html)

```py
# plot the dataframe in an axes level plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 5))
sns.kdeplot(data=df, x='x', y='y', hue='label', ax=ax)
```

[image]